# 'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAuthzPluginException Unsupported privilege type All'

Tags: hive, odbc

I'm trying to query Hive over ODBC. I granted `all` privileges to a user, then got this message:

`'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAuthzPluginException Unsupported privilege type All'`

So I went back and granted `select` to the ODBC user but I still get the same message:

`'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAuthzPluginException Unsupported privilege type All'`

what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get into this issue if you try to grant privileges on Hive Cli.
You may need to clean privilege "All" from metastore DB. 
Here is the nice blog 
http://www.openkb.info/2015/07/query-fails-with-error.html

Answer (score 1):

Although this is very old, I still feel somebody may need it.

I faced similar issue after creating table in hive from a spark session in python (pyspark), with Hive SQL standard Authorization enabled. All I did was to modify "hive.security.authorization.createtable.owner.grants" in **hive-site.xml** file that was referenced by the pyspark session.

**Initial** value -

```
<property>
 <name>hive.security.authorization.createtable.owner.grants</name>
 <value>ALL</value>    
</property>
```

**Modified** value -

```
<property>
 <name>hive.security.authorization.createtable.owner.grants</name>
 <value>SELECT</value>    
</property>
```

If, however, Hive is not hardened with Hive SQL standard Authorization, this problem will not appear which is what I have tested with 2 different hive instances.

Comment: That makes sense. This was my question but, to your point, it was 7 years ago so I'm not in a position to be able to test the solution now.